# jQuery load() and ASP.NET MVC URL path

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am creating an MVC web app, and I want to load some page content in via AJAX using jQuery.load(). I have this working, but the problem is that I have to pass the ENTIRE URL in, including the http:// part, or it won't work. In other words, a relative URL path is failing.

So, this **works**:

```
$('#params').empty().load('http://localhost:58438/home/getsurveydata #params', val);
```

This **fails**:

```
$('#params').empty().load('/home/getsurveydata #params', val);
```

Every example I see on the web seems to indicate that the second form should work just fine. Any thoughts?

*FWIW I tried removing the 'val' part and the #params part, but that made no difference. It doesn't even hit the controller. And like I said, it works in the first format with as written, the URL is the only difference. What am I missing?*

Comment: Can you enable firebug network monitor and see if the request is made? Some other javascript error might be happening that is stopping the call.

Answer (score 3):

How about using HTML5 data-* attributes on the `#params` container:

```
<div id="params" data-url="@Url.Action("getsurveydata", "home")"></div>
```

Now in your separate javascript you can write:

```
var p = $('#params');
p.empty().load(p.data('url') + ' #params', val);
```

This will work no matter where the application is deployed and it avoids you from hardcoding any urls as it relies on url helper to generate it so if you decide to change the layout of your routes in Application_Start you won't need to modify anything on the UI part.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't make sense to me why it doesn't work, but worse-case scenario you can make it dynamic by using this:

`$('#params').empty().load('http://@HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Authority/home/getsurveydata #params', val);`